# Copy files for backup and append date

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am using below script to append current date to a file when copying and making a backup. However, I have multiple excel files in the C:\Test directory. I would like to pass each filename as a variable, and append the date when making a copy to C:\Test\Archive\Processed directory.

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime ^| find "."') do set DateTime=%%a

set Yr=%DateTime:~0,4%
set Mon=%DateTime:~4,2%
set Day=%DateTime:~6,2%

set BackupName=File Name__%Yr%-%Mon%-%Day%

copy "C:\Test\*" "C:\Test\Archive\Processed\%BackupName%.xlsx"
```

Desired output:

```
FilenameA__2019-03-20.xlsx
FilenameB__2019-03-20.xlsx
FilenameC__2019-03-20.xlsx
...
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You'll need a for to process input files and individually attach the stamp using the tilde modifiers for the file name parts path, name, extension see `for /?` or view online [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html), together with the [`~` modifiers](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) of the loop meta-variable:

```cmd
for %%I in ("C:\Test\*.xlsx") do (
    copy "%%~I" "C:\Test\Archive\Processed\%%~nI__%Yr%-%Mon%-%Day%%%~xI"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your `copy` statement, put something like this (not tested):

```
FORFILES /M *.xlsx /C "cmd /c copy @file C:\Test\Archive\Processed\@fname_%BackupName%.xlsx"
```

Comment: `forfiles` can of course be used (note that it also returns matching directories though), but why not using a standard [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html), which is going to be way faster?

Comment: @aschipfl. I'm sorry, I'm not aware of `forfiles` performance issues.

Comment: @Dominique, For every file that is found a new `CMD.exe` instance is opened to process the file.  That is a huge overhead. The only reason ever to use `FORFILES` is if you need to use the `/D` option.